# THREE JS Raycaster

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to select only a specific object by clicking the mouse in THREE JS

Now the function is executed by clicking on any point, although the condition states the name mesh

```
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100);
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x9370DB});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
cube.position.y = 50;
cube.name = "cube";
scene.add(cube);

const sizeBox = 30;
const geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(sizeBox, sizeBox, sizeBox);
const mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
});
const earth = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);

earth.position.set(-300, sizeBox/2, 10);

scene.add(earth);
```

const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onMouseClick( event ) {

```
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );


const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

console.log(intersects);

for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
  console.log(intersects[ i ].name)
    
    if(intersects[ i ].name = 'cube') {
        gsap.to(camera.position, {z: 100, duration: 10})
    }
    

}
```

}

window.addEventListener( 'click', onMouseClick, false );

Comment: if (intersects[ i ].name = 'cube') {
        gsap.to(camera.position, {z: 100, duration: 10})
    }

You're not testing anything in that "if" statement. It should be "===" instead of "=".

Comment: @Zabon that is a (the?) right answer. You should post this as an answer too!

Answer (score 1):

```js
if (intersects[ i ].name = 'cube') { 
    gsap.to(camera.position, {z: 100, duration: 10})
}
```

You're not testing anything in that "if" statement. It should be "===" instead of "=".

Answer (score 1):

In your **THREE.js** code, you're attempting to select a specific object by clicking the mouse. Let's address the issue and ensure that only the cube is selected when clicked.

Here are the key points to consider:

1. **Raycasting**: To determine which object is under the mouse cursor, you can use raycasting. It involves casting a ray from the camera in the direction of the mouse position and checking for intersections with objects in the scene.
2. **Event Handling**: You've already set up an event listener for mouse clicks. Inside the `onMouseClick` function, you'll perform the raycasting and handle the selection logic.
3. **Intersecting Objects**: The `intersects` array contains information about the objects intersected by the ray. You can access the `name` property of each intersected object to identify it.
4. **Condition for Cube Selection**: In your case, you want to select the cube. Therefore, check if the intersected object's name is equal to `'cube'`.

Here's an updated version of your `onMouseClick` function:

```js
function onMouseClick(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);

  for (let i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
    const intersectedObject = intersects[i].object;
    console.log(intersectedObject.name);

    if (intersectedObject.name === 'cube') {
      // Example: Move the camera closer to the cube
      gsap.to(camera.position, { z: 100, duration: 10 });
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('click', onMouseClick, false);
```